# Does the Executioner Assassin's Attack Finesse apply to all targets of that attack?

Tags: dnd-4e

Today, wizards released the [Ninja](http://wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/dra/201110assassin#76809) guild option for the executioner assassin.

As one of its powers, it gets poisonous shuriken:

> Target: One, two, or three creatures
>
> Attack: Dexterity vs. AC
>
> Hit: 1[W] damage.

Given that this is "Martial, Weapon" attack, does Attack Finesse apply to all targets or a single target:

> In addition, once per turn you can deal 1d8 extra damage with a weapon attack using a one-handed weapon, a garrote, a blowgun, or a shortbow. The extra damage increases to 2d8 at 11th level and 3d8 at 21st level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You only add your Attack Finesse damage to one target**

Attack Finesse allows you to "deal extra damage with a weapon attack"

Each target of Poisoned Shuriken is attacked separately. The facts that they share a 1W damage roll, or that all 1, 2 or 3 attacks happen at the same time, as part of the same power, are of no consequence.

Answer (score 1):

I asked @DaveTheGame (author of the article): "Awesome ninja article. Question: Does Finesse apply to all targets of shuriken?" , and he [responded](https://twitter.com/#!/DaveTheGame/status/123920443408265216):

> @DenubisX Only one of the targets, since it's 1/Rd.

While the compendium says it applies once per turn, the central point remains.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, but it is very hard to argue with author's intent.